# How to solve Cannot read property 'listeners' of null in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am using the following packages for my React project.

```
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "react-router": "3.0.0",
    "react-cookie": "1.0.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "react":"^15.4.1"
```

Inside componentWillMount function i'm checking my cookie value, if it's not match, i just forward to my home page.

For forward page, i'm using

```
hashHistory.push('/');
```

Here i'm getting error like

```
error TypeError: Cannot read property 'listeners' of null
at ReactDOMComponent.unmountComponent (ReactDOMComponent.js:966)
at Object.unmountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:78)
at Object.unmountChildren (ReactChildReconciler.js:146)
at ReactDOMComponent.unmountChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:371)
at ReactDOMComponent.unmountComponent (ReactDOMComponent.js:990)
at Object.unmountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:78)
at Object.unmountChildren (ReactChildReconciler.js:146)
at ReactDOMComponent.unmountChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:371)
at ReactDOMComponent.unmountComponent (ReactDOMComponent.js:990)
at Object.unmountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:78)
```

How can i solve this error.Please give my solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you use `hashHistory` ? why not the more preferred `browserHistory` ?

Comment: This is already developed by someone they done with hashHistory, so i'm just maintaining that.